# Wrong behavior in Backups

Tags: sql-server, backup

Checking my Native backup this morning something wierd happened. I will describe the problem here.

1) The msdb table backup set shows me the backup was done successfully.

2) The errorlog shows me that the backup was done successfully.

3) The job history doesn't show any entry, even it is successfully or error.

4) Checking the backup media family table the physical device name column shows me something like this: {F2F1E11C-589A-4AAE-8880-0120D8D1998D}1
and other days it shows me the right directory of my backups.

4) The DPM also do system state and database backup after the SQL Server Backup and runs well.

Well.. if anyone need more informations, please let me know.

Thanks.
Marcos Freccia
@SqlFreccia

Comment: The physical device name of a GUID means the backup didn't really finish successfully, OR that it's a device-based backup (like tape or DPM).

Comment: So, I assume when a DPM backup finish it also insert a record in msdb backups table?

Comment: Yeah, DPM backups (as long as they're SQL ones) will also be reflected in MSDB.  If you do a system-state-only backup then it won't.

Answer (score 1):

This can be VSS based DPM backups. Do you also have info in the Errorlog about "I/O Frozen for database xxx" and "I/O thawed for database xxx" ? That is sign of VSS (Snapshot) backups. If you rely on that kind of backups you should (as always) ensure that you can restore the backups, and you should pay special attention to Log backups.

Comment: Yep.. there are these entries in errorlog, but the DPM backup is 2 or 3 hours after the SQL Backup.